# Rails - counter_cache not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

I'm building an events app using Rails and have added a counter_cache association between my Event and Booking models in order to capture the number of bookings made on each event.

I'v added a line of code to my Event show page specifically for the creator of the event to show them how many bookings have been made -

```
 <% if user_signed_in? and current_user == @event.user %>
                        <button><%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path %></button>
                        <button> <%= link_to "Delete", event_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></button>
                        <p><%= pluralize @event.bookings_count.size, 'booking' %></p>
```

All of the current events I have set up show exactly the same number of bookings (8 bookings) -
[image: Example for bookings]

When I try and add a booking it doesn't update. What am I doing wrong?

This is my migration from when I added bookings_count to my Events table -

```
class AddBookingsCountToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_column :events, :bookings_count, :integer, default: 0
    Event.reset_column_information
    Event.all.each do |e|
      Event.update_counters e.id, :bookings_count => e.bookings.length
    end


  end
end
```

Do I need to add anything in my Events controller? I've set my Booking model up as per the Guides -

```
 belongs_to :event, counter_cache: true
```

Do I need to add anything to my Event model?

Comment: Slight side note: It is a bad idea to reference models (i.e. `Event`) from inside a migration. This is because if you ever rename them, your old migrations will become invalid (syntax errors due to undefined constants/methods). Furthermore, the way you have placed initialisation logic (`Event.update_counters`) inside the `change` method makes the migration irreversible in its current form!

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't aware. This was how it was done on Railscasts albeit these are quite old videos. Any idea how I can fix the issue?

Comment: can u debug the value you're updating in the migration? simply puts e.bookings.length

Comment: Interestingly, when I change from event.bookings_count.size to event.bookings_count then it does seem to work albeit it doesn't recognise quantity, so if I book 2 spaces on an event the bookings number only increases by 1 not 2.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead the [rails cast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) is using an `up` and `down` method, which is why their migration is reversible, whereas yours is not! The concept of not including models in the migration, however, was a lesson that the community learned over time - as it was not so obvious at first what problems it would cause.

Comment: To be fair, if you are confident that the `Event` model will never be renamed, then it's *probably* going to be OK referencing it like this. Just something to be aware of in general though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't envisage ever needing to change the name as this is the core model in the app.

Answer (score 1):

This was simply a case of poor code on my part, I used -

```
 <p><%= pluralize @event.bookings_count.size, 'booking' %></p>
```

It actually should have been -

```
 <p><%= pluralize @event.bookings.size, 'booking' %></p>
```

However, this would have still used the database to count, thus, rendering the usage of the counter_cache redundant so using this -

```
<p><%= pluralize @event.bookings_count, 'booking' %></p>
```

gives me the output I was looking for and also leveraging from counter_cache in the way intended.